# How to SHDocVw.InternetExplorer open panel controls

Tags: internet-explorer, c#-4.0

c#  SHDocVw.InternetExplorer  com  show panel control add

my codes

```
        var IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();

        object URL = "http://arena-fm-arena.fm.tc/";



        ShowWindow((IntPtr)IE.HWND, 3);
        IE.Navigate2(ref URL);
        panel1.Controls.Add(IE);
```

Comment: Please check your code, the [InternetExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa752084) is an object, instead of Control type. Do you mean you want to show the page content (http://arena-fm-arena.fm.tc/) in the panel container?

Comment: yes ! thank you  panel